# How do i reference a Form with a global variable within Subforms and do stuff to it?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I never used an English Access version, so forgive me if I explain the question poorly. 
I'm working on an old access vba application. It has a main form  named `Form_GUI`. `Form_GUI` has multiple tabs, each with it's own 'main form' and a couple different sub forms. These build up the FrontEnd. All of them are connected with various BackEnd tables from a different database.

How can I declare the variable `p_FrmZuordnung` globally and in a way that I can reference it when I want to make some changes to `Form1` or `Form2` within another form like `Form3`?

I want subforms to react differently, based on the value of this variable.

Examples of things I want to do with `p_FrmZuordnung` are below.

Things i tried:

I tried declaring it as String and simple adding it to the code.

```
Public p_FrmZuordnung As String
```

I tried delcaring it as Form like this:

```
Public p_FrmZuordnung As Form
```

And then setting it up like this:

```
Set p_FrmZuordnung = Forms!Form1
```

And using it like this within another form like `Form3`:

```
p_FrmZuordnung!somecontrolelement.requery
```

The code I wrote to identify the page within the main form works.
The code I wrote to reference the variable to a form doesn't.

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public p_FrmZuordnung As Form
Public Sub p_ErmittleFrmZuordnung()

p_FrmZuordnung = "keine Zuordnung"

Select Case Form_Form_GUI.RegisterStr1.Pages(Form_Form_GUI.RegisterStr1.Value).Name

Case "pgeVerbMassnahmen"

Set p_FrmZuordnung = Forms("Form1")

Case "pgeKVPMassnahmen"

Set p_FrmZuordnung = Forms("Form2")

End Select
End Sub
```

My goal is to use `p_frmZuordnung` in other subforms like that within `Form3`:

```
Private Sub btnCancel_Click()

Me.Undo
DoCmd.Close acForm, "Form3", acSaveYes
p_FrmZuordung.somecontrolelement.Requery

Exit Sub
End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub btnSaveAndClose_Click()

Me.txt_Kontrolle.Value = 1

If Me.Form.Dirty And Me.txt_Text.Locked = False Then
p_FrmZuordnung.txtHilfstextFokus.SetFocus
p_FrmZuordnung.Form.Dirty = True

Debug.Print p_FrmZuordnung.Form.Dirty
Me.Form.Dirty = False
End If

Me.txt_Kontrolle.Value = 0
DoCmd.Close acForm, "Form3", acSaveNo

Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Comment: For my understanding: When will `p_ErmittleFrmZuordnung()` be called and by which procedure(s)?

Comment: p_ErmittleFrmZuordnung will be called in the register element of Form_GUI. It's called RegisterStr1. It's in the Sub RegisterStr1_Change aánd works fine.

Comment: Another question to fully understand your situation: Are `Form1` and `Form2` separately opened forms, or are they placed in subform controls of the register elements pages?

Comment: Form 1 and Form 2 are sub forms within Form_GUI. They are opened when you click on the page name in the register element. They do contain various control elements, which open up other sub forms(?) on Click (for example: to type in comments; to asses risks of a process) within a seperate window. By Form 3 I mean these type of subforms.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to help me!

Answer (score 0):

Global variables must be defined in a module, not in a form.  It doesn't really matter which module you define it in. Once you declare a global variable, it is static and is accessible from any form.

The reason that you are having problems using the controls on the form, us because z_FrmZuordnung is just a generic form and the compiler cannot resolve the controls by name. You need to get the controls from the `Controls` collection.

```
Set z_FrmZuordnung = Forms!Form1
MsgBox z_FrmZuordnung.Name
'MsgBox z_FrmZuordnung.txtHilfstextFocus.Name '<--gives an error
MsgBox z_FrmZuordnung.Controls("txtHilfstextFokus").Name '<--This works
z_FrmZuordnung.Controls("txtHilfstextFokus").SetFocus
```

Comment: I defined it in a module. p_FrmZuordnung gets the name of some of the subforms in FORM_GUI.

Comment: My goal ist to use p_FrmZuordnung instead of the "real" Form name. For Example the Form's name is ThisIsForm1. I want p_FrmZuordnung to point to ThisIsForm1. And i want to be able to use p_FrmZuordung to make changes to ThisIsForm1. Like: p_FrmZuordnung.RandomElementOnThisIsForm1.requery

Answer (score 0):

As you told us now, the forms `Form1` and `Form2` are in subform controls of register control pages.

So you can't reference them by `Forms("Form2")`, because they are not 'stand alone' forms.

Instead you have to know the **name of the each subform control** which holds such a subform. The name of the form which is stored in each of this controls doesn't matter at all then.

So my suggestion is that you name those subform controls with the same name as the containing page, but adding a static suffix like `SubFormControl` (or any other suffix you like).

So for example the subform control which is on the page `pgeVerbMassnahmen` should be named `pgeVerbMassnahmenSubFormControl`.

Then you can reference the subform controls by the name of the page and the static suffix.

So I think this is what you need:

Declare a form variable in the `Form_GUI` (as long as you just reference the variable from code inside `Form_GUI`, it can be private):

```
Private p_FrmZuordnung As Form
```

I expect that `p_ErmittleFrmZuordnung` is located in the form `Form_GUI` too, so you can use `Me` to reference `Form_GUI`:

```
Private Sub p_ErmittleFrmZuordnung()
    Const SUFFIX As String = "SubFormControl"

    Dim currentPagename As String
    currentPagename = Me("RegisterStr1").Pages(Me("RegisterStr1").Value).Name

    Select Case currentPagename
        Case "pgeVerbMassnahmen"
            Set p_FrmZuordnung = Me(currentPagename & SUFFIX).Form
        Case "pgeKVPMassnahmen"
            Set p_FrmZuordnung = Me(currentPagename & SUFFIX).Form
        Case Else
            p_FrmZuordnung = Nothing
    End Select
End Sub
```

Edit:

If all pages contain a subform control you can shorten it:

```
Private Sub p_ErmittleFrmZuordnung()
    Const SUFFIX As String = "SubFormControl"

    Set p_FrmZuordnung = Me(Me("RegisterStr1").Pages(Me("RegisterStr1").Value).Name & SUFFIX).Form
End Sub
```